# MongoDB Hive Connectivity - JAR Issue

Tags: mongodb, hive

This is about establishing connectivity between HIVE and MongoDB using the MongoDB driver. I have been through the links online and have noticed that many people just breeze through it.

However I have been facing major issues in just getting the connectivity established.

Firstly, I am using the Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.5 on my Windows 64 bit system.
This VM hosts the Hadoop sandbox.

I have MongoDB installed on my desktop (the same one which also hosts the Cloudera VM). There is no authentication for the MongoDB database.

I had downloaded the 3 connectivity jars to be used to connect the 2 environments.

Here is a list of steps: -

1. Created Collection on MongoDB and populated data. MongoDB database server running on port 27017
2. Started Hive shell and 
   Added the following jars into the classpath: -

> ```
> mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar
> mongo-hadoop-hive-2.0.2.jar
> mongo-java-driver-3.5.0.jar
> ```

(The last one - the Mongo-java-driver was downloaded from a site that was referred to from mongodb itself)

I uploaded the above jars into HDFS in the directories mentioned below and then finally launched the HIVE shell and added the jars in the hive shell itself: -

```
> ADD JAR hdfs:///tmp/hive/mongo/mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar; 
> ADD JAR hdfs:///tmp/hive/mongo/mongo-hadoop-hive-2.0.2.jar; 
> ADD JAR hdfs:///tmp/hive/mongo/mongo-java-driver-3.5.0.jar;
```

Then I run this command from the HIVE shell which is supposed to work: -

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE RAVINE
>     ( 
>       id INT,
>       h_name STRING,
>       h_age INT  
>     )
>     STORED BY "com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler"
>     WITH  SERDEPROPERTIES ('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"id":"_id","h_name":"name","h_age":"a
> ge"}')     TBLPROPERTIES("mongo.uri"="mongodb://100.96.237.185:27017/test.beehive");
> ```

The error I get is the same as mentioned above by Arvind: -

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. com/mongodb/util/JSON

I went through the cloudera logs to see what the error was and stumpled upon this log: -

log file from cloudera

[image]

If you were to see the above error log. It says

> "failed to read jar file", java.util.zip.zipcollection invalid END
>   header (bad central directory offset)

This is quite confusing because I had obtained this same jar file -> the "mongo-java-driver" from https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/

Why will a jar downloaded from the same site result in this type of error? I assumed the possibility of a corrupt jar file so I tried downloading various driver versions from 3.5.0. all the way down to 3.0.4!! No change - the same error.

Now here is my question. On the site to download the java driver, Mongodb displays a maven dependancy: -

[image]

So my question is quite simple !! How can a jar downloaded from the mongoDB website give me such errors - such as bad offset !!

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do next, most of the links on the web such as  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Hive-Usage
seem to sound that this is a very straightforward easy 30 minute process, but it has taken me days to get to this state.

Any help or even suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These jars should be on your local unix directory not on HDFS. Put all these jars in some directory on UNIX box from where you are running the Hive query then add it like.

`hive> ADD JAR /home/hive/mongo/mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar;`

If it still doesn't work try downgrading to `v1.5.1` of `mongo-hadoop-*.jar`

Please see the similar issue related to this. [Unable to connect Hive with MongoDB using mongo-hadoop connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566804/unable-to-connect-hive-with-mongodb-using-mongo-hadoop-connector/45569303#comment78143865_45569303)

Comment: Thanks Sandeep for the reply. I added the jars from the local centos VM (as you suggested)  -> still got the same error. I downgraded the jars to "mongo-hadoop-hive-1.5.1.jar" and "mongo-hadoop-core-1.5.1.jar" but still got the same error. (Incidentaly these 2 jars weren't the ones which were throwing the error). The jar that seemed to be throwing the error was MongoDB's own jar - "mongo-java-driver-3.5.0.jar". Which as you can see - I have tried older versions right down to 2.14.2. Am I missing something here - the link on github indicates that this process is a breeze !!